# window login when web application is using network share in IIS 6

Tags: networking, iis, share, unc

I have installed a web application which is configured using a network drive
But i am keep getting a pop up asking for credentials
looking in the event log, the network logon is set to my domain/account which looks fine
however caller user name is empty (not sure if this is an issue)

the application works fine when i use a local drive
the application also runs fine when i set "connect as" user
the application also works fine when a share on the local machine is used!!

direct asses using the unc path is not a problem

Please advise what i can do or should check

Thanks and Regards,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely running into the double hop issue: [link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx)

It's possible to overcome the issue by setting delegation, although it's not extra easy.

Setting the "connect as" also resolves this, as you noted.  It just means that all traffic funnels through that user rather than retaining the original user for access to the network resource.

You can also switch to basic auth over SSL, which also works.

Comment: Thanks Scott, this really helped me out! 
I am using kerberos now and it seems to work

Thanks again!

James

Comment: Great!  Pleased that that helped.